# mod_rewrite causing $_POST to not get to PHP

Tags: php, forms, apache, mod-rewrite

Firstly, here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

# check if url ends in a slash and if it does redirect to same url without one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(([^/]+/)*([^/.]+))/\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*([^/.]+))/$ http://localhost/example/$1 [R=301,L]

# extionless url rewrite for urls in form example.com/cmd
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L,QSA]

# extionless url rewrite for urls in form example.com/cmd/action
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?cmd=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]

# extionless url rewrite for urls in form example.com/cmd/ajax
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?cmd=$1&action=$2&ajax=$3 [L,QSA]
```

So this works for url rewriting fine. But when I look in Firebug at my request after submitting a form to PHP it is status 303 Move Permanently. I'm fairly certain the problem is this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*([^/.]+))/$ http://localhost/example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I don't know how to fix it. I want to keep the mod_rewrite doing exactly what it is doing functionality wise, but I need this problem fixed.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I also want to mention, that if I send data from JavaScript to PHP using jquery .ajax and have type to post, it does work. And also, $_GET works no matter what. Just $_POST not working when sent from HTML to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You're forcing a client-side redirect, which means the browser will request the specified new page via a GET - that's where your form data is being lost. POST data is not preserved over a redirect, since the new page is not being loaded via POST.

Comment: So how can I get around this problem? I realize it's being lost. But I  don't know enough about mod_rewrites to know how to modify mine to work correctly. Btw, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Any reason you'd be passing query variables when you're doing a POST request? Those query vars could just be embedded in the form as hidden fields.

Comment: Yes, those query variables are necessary. I have a front controller pattern set up in a framework I'm making, and cmd and action are the 2 variables that pretty much run it.

So like if a user goes to /example/profile/someThing, my framework will send the user to index.php?cmd=profile&action=someThing, then index.php (my front controller) uses profile to call the right command, and someThing to call the right method of the command.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way I can modify my mod_rewrite so that I don't have to do the redirect this way? I mean, it can't really be so that anyone who uses redirects can't have forms be submitted via post without us JavaScript, can it?

Comment: Are you saying in my form have action be something like "action='example/'". Are you saying that doing this would cause it to bypass that rule? But, isn't that rule taking any url and stripping the slash off of it? Maybe I don't understand what you're saying completely.

Comment: Because how it works now, I pass all urls as example/cmd/action and it gets rewritten to index.php?cmd=cmd&action=action.

Comment: That's fine, just don't do a client-side redirect (`R=301`). Once you take that off, it becomes an in-server redirect only and the client never sees anything different.

Comment: So are you suggesting to simply remove the R=301 part then? I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why it worked Marc, but just adding the / to the end of my url in the action attribute of my form worked! Care to explain to me? I'd love to give you rep but apparently I can't without 15 rep of my own.